# Python Beautiful Soup Sometimes saves images without file extension and a file size of 0 bytes

Tags: python, image, save

I'm trying to scrape some image off a website, and most of them save correctly. However I've got one image that is being saved without a file extension and the file properties say it's size is 0 bytes and size on disk is 288kb. It loads a blank image if I manually add the .jpg extension and try to open it.

I also am trying to keep the names the same and add a number to the end like filename-1.jpg or filename-2.jpg to items with multiple images. But on some images it chops off the number as well even when it's passed to the writer.

There's no errors or crashes when I run my code, I can't figure out why the same code produces different results. Any thoughts or feedback would be appreciated.

My save image function looks like this:

```
#dir = 'C:/Users/path'
#name = 'filename.jpg'
#name = 'filename-2.jpg'
#name = 'otherFile.jpg'
#img_url will load the correct image in the browser no issues, and I can right-click and save that image and get the .jpg file no issues.

    def save_img(self, img_url, name, dir):
        #img_url[-4:] just appends the file extension to the file name
        name = self.clean_name(name) + img_url[-4:]
        name = name.replace('/', '-')

        newImage = dir + "/" + name
        if os.path.exists(newImage) == False:
            with open(newImage, "wb") as f:  #I can check here
                f.write(requests.get(img_url).content)

#result 1:
#newImage = 'C:/Users/path/filename.jpg'
#output = 'C:/Users/path/filename' #can't open no data

#result 2:
#newImage = 'C:/Users/path/filename-2.jpg'
#output = 'C:/Users/path/filename' #can't open no data

#result 3:
#newImage = 'C:/Users/path/otherFile.jpg'
#output = 'C:/Users/path/otherFile.jpg' #works just fine
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will solve your issue, but you can try just checking for the proper file extension, and if it does not exist, append it.

```
def add_suffix(file_name, file_extension):
    if not file_name.endswith(file_extension):
        return file_name + file_extension
```

I hope it helps a bit.

EDIT:

I think I found a better solution to saving files.
You can use

```
import urllib.request

def save_img(img_url, name, dir_name):
    full_path = dir_name + name
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(img_url, full_path)
```

I hope now you can scrape web freely :)

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but unfortunately that doesn't help with my situation. I can add the extension back to the file in the properties, but it's still a 0 byte file and loads a blank image. When I check the name here:  '''with open(newImage, "wb") as f:''' newImage has the file extension there with it, but it isn't writing properly. I'd suspect maybe a loading issue, but it's always with the same images which are less than 1mb in size usually only a few hundred kb. So I just don't know why it'd have a hard time loading the image.

Comment: I edited my last solution. Hope it helps.